# Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/xlrd/

Tags: python

I get this error in when I try to run this command `pip install xlrd` in my cmd. I used the cmd with elevated privilege but still to no avail.

Whole error:

```
C:\Users\Rodne>pip install xlrd
Collecting xlrd
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/xlrd/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xlrd (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for xlrd
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have python 3.6

I tried upgrading and this is what came out:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pip setuptools --upgrade
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\rodne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\rodne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

using the trusted installation gave me this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org xlrd
Collecting xlrd
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/xlrd/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xlrd (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for xlrd
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make `pypi.python.org`, `pypi.org` and `files.pythonhosted.org` trusted hosts to get around the SSL certificate verification issue:

```
pip install --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org xlrd
```

Comment: Use the above command to `install --upgrade` **pip** as well: all three trusted-host entries.